# How do I get access to the editor in froala editor in angular 11?

Tags: angular, froala

I'm using the froala editor in angular 11. I'm able to get the editor running, but how do I get access to the editor in my component.ts file?

Here is my html code:

```
<div [froalaEditor]="options"></div>
```

Here is the code in my component.ts file:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';

  public options: Object = {
    fullPage: true,
    toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', '|', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', '-', 'undo', 'redo','|', 'fullscreen'],
    events: {
      contentChanged: this.textChanged,
      click: this.didClick,
      initialized: this.didInitialize(),
    },
  };

  didInitialize() {
    console.log("initialized")
    editor.fullscreen.toggle()
  }

  textChanged() {

  }

  didClick() {

  }
}
```

For example, in the didInitialize() function, how to I get a reference to the editor to execute the fullscreen.toggle() method?

Comment: You could use @ViewChild

Comment: Does froala have documentation? If yes, have you read it? There might be samples there.

Answer (score 3):

another way

```html
<div (froalaInit)="initializeEditor($event)"></div>
```

```js
public initializeEditor(e) {
  e.initialize();
  const editor = e.getEditor();
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I figured this out. Here is the modified code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app'
  editor:any

  public options: Object = {
    fullPage: true,
    toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', '|', 'undo', 'redo','|', 'fullscreen'],
    events: {
      "initialized": (e:any) => {
        this.editor = e.getEditor()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The key was to have a parameter of type any in the initialed function and then call getEditor() on this parameter.